# Set full path of the framework in the linkwith.cs

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, gstreamer

I try to bind my native Objective-C library which uses GStreamer to my Xamarin.iOS application, but get an issue:
my library set GStreamer framework in Framework Search Paths, not in Additional SDKs.
But, when I configure my linkwith.cs in the bindings library I can't just set GStreamer to Framework property like this: `Frameworks = "GStreamer"`, because I get:

> Error MT5309: Native linking error: framework not found GStreamer (MT5309) (GstreamerIOS)

So I need to set full path of this SDK: `~/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk`(if I set this path in the Frameworks property I also get an error above) or something like Framework Search Paths like in the Xcode.

So how can I do this in the my bindings library(linkwith.cs)?

**UPD:**

/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework:
[image]

Comment: The GStreamer.framework should house the respective static library / headers inside. You could append the `.a` extension to the static library and then generate the respective API definitions via Objective Sharpie. You can then use `LinkWith("GStreamer.a")`. Otherwise see the definition of the `LinkWith.Frameworks` Attribute: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference/#LinkWithAttribute.Frameworks

Comment: @JonDouglas thanks for your response! 1. Ok, if I understood right l need to check the pairs of header/static library in the /GStreamer/iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework which my library will use and then use `LinkWith(%gstreamer_static_libraries%)` in the bindings library of my Objective-C library which uses GStreamer. Right? 2. How can I check which static libraries my library uses? I mean that I only include headers and linker does this nasty job for me.

Comment: @JonDouglas 3. I can't open Libraries dir in the /iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework(please check screen in the updated question), but my iOS Gstreamer apps works fine, so it's ok, but I just don't know how I can open it. 4. For which purposes in my case I need to use Objective Sharpie? I know what it is, but I map my static library which uses Gstreamer by myself.